# I want to display random images on different pages without repetition from database in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

View:

```
<?php
$bnrDone = createDynamicBanner();
if (count($bnrDone) === 1):
?>
    <div class="ads-dv under_search">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="inner_ads_sys">
                    <a href="<?php echo $bnrDone[0]['ad_url']?>">
                        <img  src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/advertisements/'.$bnrDone[0]['ad_dp']); ?>" class="img-fluid" alt="<?php echo $bnrDone[0]['ad_title']?>">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php 
endif; 
?>
```

Helper:

```
function createDynamicBanner()
{
    $CI = & get_instance();
    return $CI->db->distinct()
                  ->select('ad_id,ad_title,ad_url,ad_status,ad_dp')
                  ->order_by('rand()')
                  ->limit(1)
                  ->from('advertisements')
                  ->where('ad_status',1)
                  ->get()
                  ->result_array();
    //echo $CI->db->last_query();
}
```

Now Surprisingly my stupid stubborn method (Or Am I) is returning 1 for any value even if I exclude the betwwen clause part it still returns 1

Comment: remove `limit` to get more images

Comment: What to you want to express if you say `it returns 1`? Also the displayed code won`t help to save you from repetition.

Answer (score 0):

Idea 1) Could you use the Singleton pattern to create a queue object that has all the images listed?  Then your calls to the queue would retrieve the next image.

Idea 2) Alternatively, you could save state in the DB by creating a second table of image names that gets re-generated each night.  The table could have two columns, [imageName] and [usedBy], and you could get the next image where usedBy is false (null,0, whatever).  Your image fetch method would have to mark the image as used by the unique ID of the page as part of the fetch, of course, perhaps as a SQL transaction for safety.

A lot will depend on your anticipated traffic volume.